# How does this script generate a random image?

Tags: image, random

I found this script by accident: http://lorempixel.com/250/250/business/?a=7

But I have zero idea how it works. There is nothings in the code. If I try to save the page I only get the image save pop up. Can someone give me a hint, because this is absolutely fantastic!

Comment: Seems like true query thing has nothing to do with randomizing the images. It is done on the server with almost any language you can think of. For example, the URL might point to a PHP script that globs all image files in a directory and spits one out by random.

Answer (score 0):

you can have an array of image names perhaps. Each time you open the page, a random number from 0 to size of the array is generated. And the display the page with the name in the element of the array, with the random index?
say you have an array with 3 names: pic1.png pic2.jpg pic3.gif.
have a `var pic=array[Math.floor(3*Math.random())];`
and a `img src=pic;`

Answer (score 0):

In the code I found this line:

```
img ...(some crapy css styles)... src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/business/?a=7"
```

So, how it works:

1. You choose a size and category of pictures (adress shows that you are navigating to folders "250", "250" and then "businnes", I guess the numbers stand for the size.
2. Then, in this folder, lays a script that returns an image, you are passing parameter "7" into it, it can stand for a visitor ID, or it just represents some seed for the generator.
3. The script generates some random number and returns image associated with this number (you can imagine there's a 1000 of JPEGs named 1.jpg, 2.jpg and so on). Alternatively, it asks some search engine for pictures that matches those criteria (size, category) and returns them (again, "show me picture numer x after searching for business category and certain size").

Thing that can be confusing tho is, even refreshing the page with the same parameter (in this case 7), causes the page to load different pictures. Perhabs it remembers recently shown pictures for a specified IP number or something that identificates you (f.e. session ID stored in a cookie) and prevents the page from loading the same pictures), or the randomizing algorithim can be built in a way that it's very unprobable to get the same outcome even with the same seed or parameter (imagine you are adding numbers of miliseconds from now since last Monday, it constantly changes, right?).